# I am getting the following error for all of my custom snippets every time I open Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, code-snippets

Error parsing snippet xml: Error document empty. In file Packages/User/vawp.sublime-snippet

I am on OSX 10.9.5. I have researched for days and tried a few fixes, but I get these errors every time and my snippets will not trigger.

This is how my snippets look:

```xml
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<!-- %%[ if _messagecontext != "vawp" then ]%% -->
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>vawp</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

They are directly in my Packages\User forlder.

Answer (score 0):

I added XML syntax highlighting to your question so you can see the problem easier: your snippet is, in fact, empty. You've commented out the content of the snippet between the `CDATA` tags, so there is nothing to insert when you hit the key sequence. Remove the comment markers at the beginning and end of line 3 and it should work for you.

Comment: This one may be a better example. I understand what you are saying, however this one does not work either and the above works as is for colleagues of mine using Windows.

<snippet>
 <content><![CDATA[
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
]]></content>
 <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
 <tabTrigger>table</tabTrigger>
 <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
 <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>

Comment: Please edit your original post to include your comment - it's formatting is terrible.  Matt is right, your snippet in your post *cannot* run, as there is nothing there - it's commented out.  The snippet you have included in your comment works fine - make sure you give it the `sublime-snippet` extension.